# Where are the TypeScript type declarations for Sign in With Google (GSI) library?

Tags: typescript, npm, google-signin

I'm implementing "Sign in with Google" using [the Google "GSI" library](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview). My application uses Next.js and TypeScript, so I'm looking for:

1. An `npm` package including the GSI client library.
2. TypeScript type declarations for the GSI client library.

I haven't been able to find either of these: I only see a script to load from `https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client`, and [an informal API reference here](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference).

**Where can I find the GSI library and type declarations on npm?**

Answer (score 20):

1. An NPM package for `accounts.google.com/gsi/client` does not exist, at least not yet. The only way of using it is via script tag.
2. In addition to [@types/google-one-tap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/google-one-tap) from [jameshfisher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229792/jameshfisher)'s answer, there is also [@types/google.accounts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/google.accounts).

Both `google-one-tap` or `google.accounts` can be added to tsconfig types.

tsconfig.json

```
"types": ["google-one-tap", "google.accounts"]
```

Comment: I can see that I have those types installed, and when hovering on `window.google` I can see the namespace. How can I actually use those types myself? E.g. the types for errors.

Comment: Good question, @Giesburts! You need to use namespace name ("google" in our case) and access needed interfaces/types by moving deeper with dot.

Example: ``let tokenClient: google.accounts.oauth2.TokenClient``

Comment: but in that case it will tell me that `google` is not defined, because I can't import it  how can I solve that?

Comment: do you receive errors from the typescript compiler when you building/watching your code or does just IDE highlight google with red? Also, have you included both ``"google-one-tap", "google.accounts"`` to tour types in tsconfig.json?

Answer (score 12):

These type declarations are now available! (via DefinitelyTyped)

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/google-one-tap
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/google.accounts

Answer (score 10):

Types are at [`@types/google-one-tap`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/google-one-tap) and can be used like so:

```
declare global {
  const google: typeof import('google-one-tap');
}
```

I don't know where to find the actual library on npm, though.

Comment: @Coffee-Tea the script at `https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client` works for me, but I would prefer to include the library as an npm dependency. I've also edited my answer to show how I've used the unofficial type declarations.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Types can be installed in your typescript project with NPM

```bash
npm install @types/google.accounts
```

Here is a list of TSDoc types I've bundled that might be frequently used, because I've realized whenever I search for one, I end up in this page.

```
@types/google.accounts
# Type definitions for Google Identity Services JavaScript SDK

@types/gapi
# TypeScript definitions for Google API Client

@types/gapi.client
# TypeScript definitions for Google API client

@types/gapi.client.discovery
# TypeScript definitions for API Discovery Service v1

@types/gapi.client.sheets
# TypeScript definitions for Google Sheets API v4

@types/gapi.client.drive
# TypeScript definitions for Drive API v3

@types/gapi.client.bigquery
# TypeScript definitions for BigQuery API v2

@types/gapi.client.storage
# TypeScript definitions for Cloud Storage JSON API v1

@types/gapi.client.youtube
# TypeScript definitions for YouTube Data API v3 v3

@types/gapi.client.androidpublisher
# TypeScript definitions for Google Play Android Developer API v3

@types/gapi.client.oauth2
# TypeScript definitions for Google OAuth2 API v2

@types/gapi.client.calendar
# TypeScript definitions for Calendar API v3

@types/gapi.client.gmail
# TypeScript definitions for Gmail API v1

@types/gapi.client.people
# TypeScript definitions for People API v1

@types/gapi.client.analytics
# TypeScript definitions for Google Analytics API v3

@types/gapi.client.fcm
# TypeScript definitions for Firebase Cloud Messaging API v1

@types/gapi.client.speech
# TypeScript definitions for Cloud Speech-to-Text API v1

@types/gapi.client.language
# TypeScript definitions for Cloud Natural Language API v1

@types/gapi.client.tagmanager
# TypeScript definitions for Tag Manager API v2

@types/gapi.client.analyticsadmin
# TypeScript definitions for Google Analytics Admin API v1alpha

@types/gapi.client.analyticsreporting
# TypeScript definitions for Analytics Reporting API v4

@types/gapi.client.customsearch
# TypeScript definitions for Custom Search API v1

@types/gapi.client.sqladmin
# TypeScript definitions for Cloud SQL Admin API v1

@types/gapi.client.deploymentmanager
# TypeScript definitions for Cloud Deployment Manager V2 API v2

@types/gapi.client.pubsub
# TypeScript definitions for Cloud Pub/Sub API v1

@types/gapi.client.cloudbuild
# TypeScript definitions for Cloud Build API v1

@types/gapi.client.logging
# TypeScript definitions for Cloud Logging API v2

@types/gapi.client.iam
# TypeScript definitions for Identity and Access Management (IAM) API v1

@types/gapi.auth2
# TypeScript definitions for Google Sign-In API

@types/gapi.client.translate
# TypeScript definitions for Cloud Translation API v3

@types/gapi.client.firebase
# TypeScript definitions for Firebase Management API v1beta1

@types/gapi.client.adsense
# TypeScript definitions for AdSense Management API v2

@types/gapi.client.analyticshub
# TypeScript definitions for Analytics Hub API v1beta1

@types/gapi.client.firestore
# TypeScript definitions for Cloud Firestore API v1

@types/gapi.client.firebasestorage
# TypeScript definitions for Cloud Storage for Firebase API v1beta

@types/gapi.client.dialogflow
# TypeScript definitions for Dialogflow API v3
```

Answer (score -4):

If you dont want to use the unofficial types libraries, you have an alternative as follows.

```
// initialize gsi client
(window as any).google.accounts.id.initialize({
  client_id: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  callback: onSuccess
})
// render the login button
(window as any).google.accounts.id.renderButton(
  document.getElementById('sign-in-div'),
  {
    type: 'standard'
  }
)
```

You can use `(window as any)` before you access the google object. But you need to use this **only after you know the google object will be available**.