# How to use Google GSI in typescript with React?

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, google-signin, dynamic-import

I have seen the [qustion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70665608/where-are-the-typescript-type-declarations-for-sign-in-with-google-gsi-library) about this topic. I came to some solution.

First Import the GSI client library in a script tag in HTML,

```html
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client"></script>
```

Next just import the google-one-tap for type support

```js
import * as google from "google-one-tap";
```

Now I am sure that the GSI client will load but how to suppress the error,

```bash
ERROR in ./src/components/Navigation.tsx 24:0-41
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'google-one-tap' in 'C:\Users\srilakshmikanthanp\OneDrive\Documents\Source Code\chatviewer\apps\web\src\components'
```

I have also tried directly importing from the web like,

```js
import * as google from "https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client";
```

Add added the type definition via global.d.ts like,

```js
declare module 'https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client' {
  export * from 'google-one-tap'
}
```

But this too results in,

```bash
ERROR in external "https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client"
The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax so it's not possible to use external type 'module' within a script
```

I tried to fix that by changing the target to es2020 but no results. Now how to successfully import the GSI client to React in typescript ? Thanks.